# Ajax alert on validation error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have made this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: myMethod,
    url: myRoute,
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{csrf_token()}}" },
    data: form.serializeArray(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log('validated!');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        for (error in errors) {
            alert(error);
        }
        console.log(errors);
    }
});
```

I get this response in the console:

[image]

And my alerts are those field names:

```
event_end_date
event_start_date
```

And what i want is to print those messages:

```
Endzeitpunkt muss ausgefüllt sein.
Startzeitpunkt muss ausgefüllt sein.
```

How to get them in alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use the key `error` with and index `[0]` to get the first item :

```
alert(errors[error][0]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please note that it's an array for a reason. Laravel's default errors response can have more than one error per form element. So while it might work you could be missing error messages by just showing only the first item in the array.

Comment: well let's say that you get more than one error for single item....if you try to submit the form you won't see the other errors...but you will correct that one you did see...and if you try to submit the form again the other errors will pop up so you will need to correct those again and again and again until you fill the form properly. And the fact is you can't submit the form if you don't fill it right!